# _prepareLayout() from the Template declared instead of the AbstractBlock class

Tags: magento2

- Possible dependency on implementation details. Usage of 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::_prepareLayout' should be declared instead of 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::_prepareLayout'
- This is the error that I get, may I please get a possible solution to this.
- my class is as follows :

```
class AddressBook extends Template
{
```

- then there are bunch of declarations there then for my __construct() I have the following

```
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context, 
        Session $customerSession, 
        LoggerInterface $logger, 
        CollectionFactory $countries,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository, 
        B2BManInterface $companyRepository,
        AddressRepository $addressRepository2,
        Http $http)
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->companyRepository = $companyRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->countries = $countries;
        $this->admin = false;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->addressRepository2 = $addressRepository2;
        $this->http = $http;
    }
```

from my method that I am overriding which is _prepareLayout() I have this :

```
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Company Address AddressBook'));
        $shouldSetShowPage = !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'company/users/create/')?true:false;
        if ($this->getAddressCollection()) {
            try {
                $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
                    'company.address.book.pager'
                )->setAvailableLimit([5 => 5, 10 => 10, 15 => 15, 20 => 20])
                    ->setShowPerPage($shouldSetShowPage)->setCollection(
                        $this->getAddressCollection()
                    );
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getAddressCollection()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

- is there a possible way to call Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::_prepareLayout() rather than Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::_prepareLayout.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::_prepareLayout() by:
`\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::_prepareLayout();`

But it is not a good idea because if the Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template class declares _prepareLayout method in the future, your code won't be working as expected.

Looks like you faced this error when running the Upgrade Compatibility Tool? If yes, you can ignore this error because magento core (codebase) implements the same way in many files, that is call `parent::_prepareLayout()` from the class that extends Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template, eg
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Address/Grid.php#L70

Btw, you **shouldn't** use PHP superglobals ($_SERVER) to safely access values. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/security-performance-data-bp.html#use-wrappers-instead-of-superglobal-variables

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense, we are doing an upgrade of one of our sites and I am responsible for the changes that need be to move from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.4 and I only get the errors from my team lead and he confirmed that he got this error from an Upgrade Compatibility Tool

Comment: You're welcome.